# Load contents in 2 different div

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, load

I have a page "work" with 2 div:

```
<div id="intro"></div>

<div id="images"></div>
```

Now I have lot of introductions and images and I would like to store these in different pages and when on the menu I click on specific link it load in the same page the contents of the relative page, Introduction into id#intro and images into id#images.

I don't know how to do that...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you know how to do that gets closest to what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load)** method to load content dynamically into your divs.

Comment: which one is an easy way to code it with a huge multilevel menu?

Comment: @Toro - sorry, I don't understand your question. I suggested $.load method and there is only one such method.

Comment: I mean, I have a big menu, on click on a single link it load these introductions and images from another page.

Comment: Btw i solved with a case switch for now, seems to be the best solution also if there are lot of rows in coding... thanks for your help also if I knwe about that. cheers.